# I want to execute this event every 10 minutes in my MYSQL , but it is not working can anyone suggest

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP EVENT IF EXISTS delete_name $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`LOCALHOST` 
EVENT `delete_name` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 MINUTE starts now()
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE
DO 
BEGIN
DELETE FROM CLTX_SOFS WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2017-07-07',' ','11:30:00'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') < (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE);
END $$
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Is a hard coded date what you intended?

Comment: I didn't get any error but it is not deleting any records from table ,

Comment: @P.Salmon for understanding i have hardcoded the date , there will be date field and a time column.

Comment: Store dates and times as a single entity

Comment: Maybe check whether `NOW()` is in the timezone you think it is.

Comment: @Adder i checked NOW() is working correctly it is returning in this format only 2017-07-07 11:30:00

Comment: When you SELECT LAST_EXECUTED FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS WHERE EVENT_NAME = 'DELETE_NAME'; do you get a date or null?

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, note that

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2017-07-07',' ','11:30:00'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

is equivalent to

```
'2017-07-07 11:30:00'
```

Comment: So the str_to_date stuff is redundant

Comment: i have kept date filed as varchar so i am using STR_TO_DATE conversion